# Specified cast is not valid.?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

```
protected void RegisterUser(object sender,EventArgs e) 
{
    int userid = 0;
    var s = (from a in dc.Insert_User(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim(), txtEmail.Text.Trim())
                 select a.Column1).SingleOrDefault();

   // gvtest.DataSource = s;
   // gvtest.DataBind();
    userid = Convert.ToInt32(s);
    string message = string.Empty;
    switch (userid)
    {
        case -1:
            message = "Username already exists.\\nPlease choose a different username.";
            break;
        case -2:
            message = "Supplied email address has already been used.";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Registration successful.\\nUser Id: " + userid.ToString();
            break;
    }
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

i am getting specified cast is not valid error on query when i enter new record for regsitration. the record is inserted in database as well.

here is the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_User]
  @Username NVARCHAR(20),
  @Password NVARCHAR(20),
  @Email NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  IF EXISTS(SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username)
  BEGIN
        SELECT -1 -- Username exists.
  END
  ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Email = @Email)
  BEGIN
        SELECT -2 -- Email exists.
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Users]
                 ([Username]
                 ,[Password]
                 ,[Email]
                 ,[CreatedDate])
        VALUES
                 (@Username
                 ,@Password
                 ,@Email
                 ,GETDATE())

        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- UserId                 
 END
END
```

but no such error when -1 or -2 is returned from the procedure

Comment: This is really not enough for us to say what is going wrong. You need to write a better question, giving full details of the code involved, along with a specific detail of the problem you're encountering. Please spend time making a good question so that we can give you a good answer.

Comment: now i have updated my question please review it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the most likely answer is that since IDENTITY is a numeric(32), it's more than likely the data coming back is too large for an Int32. If the identity column is a uniqueidentifier, you will probably have success casting it as a GUID type.